# Synonyms/meaning of the words "big cycle" in a contect

Tags: word-meaning

Currently reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/growing-number-republican-donors-aim-080056303.html) there is a line,

> Many of the donors on the Cheney call are expected to donate the maximum amount of $5,800 to her 2022 re-election campaign before the end of the first quarter of this year, to ward off a primary challenge to her which Trump loyalists like congressman Matt Gaetz are encouraging, said Michael Epstein, a leading Maryland Republican donor.

> “We want to show a really **big cycle** for her to scare off competition,”

How are the words "big cycle" used here? If there is a synonym, what would it be?

Comment: I didn't know the usage before, but it looks like your example references the [***Cycle of Giving***](https://brewerdirect.com/cycle-of-giving/) as it relates to "fundraising" (in this case, specifically raising funds to finance election campaigns). I'd just ignore the details and assume it means *We want a **strong response** to her initial fundraising efforts.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Okay, thanks. To be deleted within hours (if there is not an answer).

Comment: I mean, probably.

Comment: I can't see why anyone would downvote or closevote this, so I don't think it would cost you anything to leave the question up here even if you're satisfied with my comment. And it's almost certainly US "political campaign jargon" - which isn't exactly my specialist subject, so I *might* not have guessed the meaning correctly. Also, I'm just thinking what *someone else* might say if they've just spent 10 minutes laboriously composing a full answer - only to find that when they click on "Post Answer" it fails because you deleted the question while they were answering it! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Okay:)